# JAVA 2 Classes, both Public but cant access the one's class in the other

Tags: java, android, libgdx

so I've got two Classes (I'm making a Game App using libGDX, and have a 2nd Class for the Controlls.).
My 2nd Class is called Controller:

```
public class Controller {

    Viewport viewport;
    Stage stage;
    boolean upPressed, downPressed, leftPressed, rightPressed;
    OrthographicCamera cam;

public boolean isUpPressed() {
    return upPressed;
}

public boolean isDownPressed() {
    return downPressed;
}

public boolean isLeftPressed() {
    return leftPressed;
}

public boolean isRightPressed() {
    return rightPressed;
}

public Controller(){
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),cam);
    stage = new Stage(viewport, StarKing.batch);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

There is more Code, just FYI. But I dont think its relevant to the Question.

So now when I go to my MainClass to create the "controller" by doing this:

```
Controller controller;
```

It says "Cannot resolve symbol." 
Even though the Class is public. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please, show us the imports? I am suspicious that you are not pointing to your class, but other with the same name from other package or jar. Controller is common used name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your Controller class .class file is kept at another directory and class path is not set to check in that directory . You need to set the class path for the root directory where your all .class files are kept.

Comment: Nope they were not in the same folder, the MainClass was core/etc/etc.etc while the controller was in android/etc/etc

Answer (score 0):

One likely cause is that your main application class and the `Controller` class are in different packages.

If this is the case, your main class needs to `import` the `Controller` class including its package.

Also you should probably initialize your `controller` as

`Controller controller=new Controller();`

Comment: The package is exactly the same in both classes